# Doubt in a step of proof of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $a, b, p, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $\epsilon > 0$.
2. $a \leq p - \epsilon < p < p + \epsilon \leq b$.

From these two facts, which of the following can we conclude,
$(p - \epsilon, p + \epsilon) \subseteq (a, b)$ or $(p - \epsilon, p + \epsilon) \subset (a, b)$?

Note that the second one is a stronger statement, I think we can only conclude the first one and not the second one. However in many notes I am seeing the second holds. For eg: http://www.newacademicscience.co.uk/samplechapter/000055.pdf (See Example 2.4 of these notes)

Comment: You are right but many people write $\subset$ for $\subseteq$.

Comment: If $a < p < b$, then there *exists* an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the inclusion is strict... maybe that’s the source of confusion?  But with what you’ve stated, you’re correct that only the first statement necessarily holds.  You should be able to choose specific values for the variables to convince yourself of that.

Comment: The convention of using the symbol $A\subset B$ to indicate that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ is not used universally (I don't know exactly why, though I have a hypothesis): some authors use $\subset$ as synonymous with $\subseteq$, and you should always check which convention is in use.
For the record, my high-school textbook used the convention that $A\subset B$ stood for $A$ being a *non-empty* proper subset of $B$, because there isn't enough craziness in the world, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is more of a convention issue than a logical one!

Comment: Both symbols mean the same thing in typical usage.